# How to improve the arguments check in scanf?

Tags: c, types, scanf

I have the next code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char* a;
    int b;
    if(fscanf(stdin,"%s%d",a,&b)!=2){
        printf("Bad Args!!");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

when i try to add the next inputs -

**F52352354**

**5F2352354**

i get the next **output**:

For the first one - **Bad Arg**

For the second **Nothing**

another thing that makes a trouble is when i try to check about big numbers then the range of int and in the range of double i get that the input is OK.

My question is if there is an elegant way to check the parameters **(in C and not at C++)** ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, but: 1. `a` is uninitialized in the call to `fscanf`. Undefined behavior. 2. Don't use `scanf` for user input.

Comment: @melpomene thanks for your answer. 2. what is your proposal for getting input from the user?

Comment: @melpomene Why shouldn't we use `scanf()` ?

Comment: @J...S It's fundamentally incompatible with user expectations (e.g. that hitting Enter should do something: accept input, or print an error, or anything). It's hard to use correctly. Even if you get it right and detect errors, recovering from those errors is even harder or impossible.

Comment: @J...S Case in point: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46631193/1848654

Comment: @melpomene Wouldn't `scanf("%255[^\n]", msgtobesent);` be okay in that case?

Comment: @J...S No, you'd still have to check the return value. And why bother with complex format strings when you can just use `fgets`?

Comment: @melpomene But `fgets()` return value must also be checked, right? It would return `NULL` upon error.

Comment: @J...S Yes, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a `char` pointer. But it's just a pointer and *not* an array.

If you use a uninitialised pointer, which has some indeterminate (garbage) value, it points to some location which may not even be a location that the program is allowed to access or worse yet could be pointing to another process's memory which would in turn cause error.

Either use dynamic memory allocation like

```
char *a=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
if(a==NULL)
{
    perror("Not enough space");
}
```

which must be deallocated after use with `free(a)`.

Or make a statically allocated array like

```
char a[100];
```

You seem to expect to read a string and then a number. If the input is a string without numbers and then a number, you could use

```
scanf("%99[^0-9]%d", a, &b);
```

The `scanf()` would read at most 99 characters till it encounters a number, places it in `a` and the number is stored in `b`.

As [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6879826/david-bowling) pointed out, this wouldn't skip the leading white spaces. If you want to skip the leading white spaces before writing to `a`, use a space before the `%99[^0-9]` like

```
scanf(" %99[^0-9]%d", a, &b);
```

Check the return value of `scanf()` to see if `scanf()` was successful as you did.

Note that if `scanf()` fails, some characters will still be left in the input buffer and you may want to remove it.

You could do this to consume from input buffer till the next `\n`

```
int ch;
while( (ch=getchar())!='\n' && ch!=EOF );
```

`fscanf(stdin, ........)` is equivalent to `scanf(.........)`.

Comment: `while((ch = getchar()) != '\n');` --> `while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);` to avoid a potential infinite loop.

Comment: Also note that `"%99[^0-9]%d"` does not skip over leading whitespace characters, while OP's `"%s%d"` does skip over leading whitespace.

Comment: @DavidBowling Would adding  a preceding space like " %99[^0-9]%d" would skip over leading spaces?

Comment: You make it sound like "may not even be accessible to the program" is the bad thing, but it's the _best_ possible outcome.  Pointing at some of the process's (writable) memory would be much worse!  The point is that there is no (appropriate) array, as you also said.

Comment: @Davis Why is it the best thing? Can you give an example?

Comment: @J...S: Because you get a signal and immediately learn that your program is wrong (and even the approximate location of the mistake).  Undefined behavior has _many_ worse possibilities than that!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have at least 2 problems her.  `a` is a pointer to char, but scanf requires a char array.  Also, %s will get as many characters as possible until the input has finished or a space, so following it with a %d means that the %s will get all the input and the %d gets nothing.

Comment: The `%d` will just get the next number. E.g. `foo 123` would be accepted.

Comment: Yes, because there is a space between them but ``foo123`` would not put anything in the %d specifier and fail the ``if()``.